# build function signature from list of variable names

Tags: python, function, signature

I have a list of variable names:

```
var_names = ['x','y']
```

and a function that takes vector input, e.g.

```
def f(vec):
   return vec[0]+vec[1]
```

I want to build a function that creates a multi-input function that does the same thing as f, e.g.

```
def g(x,y):
   return f([x,y])
```

Does anybody know how to create a function like g in an automated way? I tried this

```
def _create_multiInput_fcn(vector_fcn,var_list):
    def g(*var_list):
        out = vector_fcn(var_list)
        return out
    return g

g = _create_multiInput_fcn(f,var_list)
```

but that just gave me something with a signature like this:

```
<function __main__._create_multiInput_fcn.<locals>.f(*var_list)>
```

when I really want this:

```
<function __main__._create_multiInput_fcn.<locals>.f(x,y)>
```

I appreciate any help/advice that someone can give me. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, how did you get those 'signatures'? I am trying something that might work but I am not sure how to check it

Comment: in ipython, i type the function name at the command line, e.g. #:] f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) to define a function dynamically:

```
def _create_multiInput_fcn(vector_fcn,var_list):
    exec('''
def g({0}):
    return vector_fcn([{0}])
'''.format(','.join(var_list)), globals(), locals())
    return g
g = _create_multiInput_fcn(f,var_list)
```

Comment: you will need `exec`, function definition statements are not expressions, and `eval` requires expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I did mean `exec` (I even linked to `exec`'s documentation) but somehow mistakenly wrote `eval` in the code.

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I run the code you posted it tells me that g does not exist. Here's what I'm doing     `var_list = ['x','y']

def f(vec):
   return vec[0]+vec[1]

def _create_multiInput_fcn(vector_fcn,var_list):
    exec('''
def g({0}):
    return vector_fcn([{0}])
'''.format(','.join(var_list)), {'vector_fcn': vector_fcn})
    return g

g = _create_multiInput_fcn(f,var_list)

g(2,3)`

Comment: @lab_rat Oops I forgot that you have to pass `globals()` instead to `exec` in order for new variables/functions to reflect in the caller's namespace. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's still telling me g does not exist. Here's the way I'm running your code: `var_list = ['x','y']

def f(vec):
   return vec[0]+vec[1]

def _create_multiInput_fcn(vector_fcn,var_list):
    exec('''
def g({0}):
    return vector_fcn([{0}])
'''.format(','.join(var_list)), globals(), locals())
    return g

g = _create_multiInput_fcn(f,var_list)

print(f([2,3]))
print(g(2,3))`

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want, but it compiles: `var_list = ['x','y']

def f(vec):
   return vec[0]+vec[1]

exec('''
def g({0}):
    return f([{0}])
'''.format(','.join(var_list))) 
    
print(f([2,3]))
print(g(2,3))`

Comment: @lab_rat Since you're defining the function that takes vector input as `f`, you should call `f` inside `g`. My code example is based on the function name you use in your question.

Comment: I can replace vector_fcn with f. It still says g is not defined. I'm closing this this now. Thank you for your help.